# Firebase Realtime Database Error for Admin Node with android java

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a login feature using Firebase Realtime Database in my Android application. I have separate nodes for "Users" and "Admins" in my database, each containing user credentials.

The authentication process for the "Users" node works perfectly as intended. However, I'm encountering issues with the authentication process for the "Admins" node. Whenever I attempt to log in with admin credentials, the `onCancelled()` method is continuously being called, indicating a problem with database access.

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

- Restarting the device and network.
- Double-checking the data in the Firebase Realtime Database.
- Verifying Firebase rules to ensure proper read access to the "Admins" node.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I suspect there might be a problem with the code handling the authentication process for the "Admins" node.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
private void checkRealtimeDatabase(String parentDpName, String enteredEmail, String password) {
    String sanitizedEmail = enteredEmail.trim().replace('.', '_').replace('#', '_').replace('$', '_').replace('[', '_').replace(']', '_');
        Log.d("Testing admin node", "checkRealtimeDatabase: sanitizedEmail" + sanitizedEmail);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(parentDpName);

    databaseReference.child(parentDpName).child(sanitizedEmail)
             .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            dismissLoadingDialog();
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                if (parentDpName.equals("Admins")) {
                    // It's an admin, check password
                    Admins admin = snapshot.getValue(Admins.class);
                    if (admin != null && admin.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                        // Password matches, start admin activity
                        startAdminActivity(enteredEmail);
                    } else {
                        // Password does not match, show error message
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid password for admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (parentDpName.equals("Users")) {
                    // It's a regular user, check password
                    Users user = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                        // Password matches, start user activity
                        startHomeActivity(enteredEmail);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Password does not match, show error message
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid password for user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // User does not exist
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handleUserNotFound();
            }
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            dismissLoadingDialog();
            // Handle database error here if needed
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.database_error_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is Realtime DB  structure
[image]

Here's a snippet of my Firebase Realtime Database rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Admins": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone please review my code and help me identify any potential issues or provide suggestions for resolving this problem?

If additional information is required, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Additional info about versions:**

- Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
- targetSdk 34
- JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
- build:gradle:7.1.0'

Comment: "indicating a problem with database access" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Do you have any errors? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: 2024-03-22 15:30:54.914  2081-3070  Volley                  com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  [67] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com/v1/GetWifiQuality?key=AIzaSyBrlVtd67QvwS_Wz0Do4ZIdOeA6ThtVczU

This is what i get in logcat

Comment: What is the exact line of code in what you have shared, that produces that error?

Comment: That URL in that error message doesn't seem to come from Firebase, so are you sure it's the Firebase-using code that is causing this?